# VBA to click IE11 Save As dialogue in Win7x64

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-11, save-as

I'm trying to get VBA to automate saving a file from IE. Thanks to various posts on these forums, I can login, navigate pages, and click the download link. The Save prompt appears at the bottom of IE, then I'm stuck:

[image: IE11 Save Dialogue]

I've been trying to use the code samples from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502298-need-help-regarding-ie-automation-using-vba-post3272730.html#post3272730, but the second FindWindow always returns 0:

```
hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString)
```

I'm using VBA 7.0 in Excel 14, and IE11.

There is advice at the top of the original post:

> 'Note - IE may block the download, displaying its Information Bar at
>   the top of the tab, and preventing this program from 'automatically
>   downloading the file.  To prevent this, add NRLDC to IE's Trusted
>   sites (Tools - Internet Options - 'Security - Trusted sites - Sites)

I can't access the trusted sites list due to IT policy, but the download prompt appears, so I don't think this is the issue.

The code I've taken is from [Doongie](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/members/doongie.html)'s [reply](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502298-need-help-regarding-ie-automation-using-vba-post3550759.html#post3550759), which indicates it's updated for Windows 7:

```
Private Sub File_Download_Click_Save()

    Dim hWnd As Long
    Dim timeout As Date

    Debug.Print "File_Download_Click_Save"

    'Find the File Download window, waiting a maximum of 30 seconds for it to appear

    timeout = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Do
        hWnd = FindWindow("#32770", "") 'returns various numbers on different runs: 20001h 10440h
        DoEvents
        Sleep 200
    Loop Until hWnd Or Now > timeout

    Debug.Print "   File Download window "; Hex(hWnd)

    If hWnd Then
        SetForegroundWindow hWnd

        'Find the child DUIViewWndClassName window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString)    'always returns 0
        Debug.Print "   DUIViewWndClassName "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If

    If hWnd Then
        'Find the child DirectUIHWND window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "DirectUIHWND", "")
        Debug.Print "   DirectUIHWND "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If

    If hWnd Then
        'Find the child FloatNotifySink window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "FloatNotifySink", "")
        Debug.Print "   FloatNotifySink "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If

    If hWnd Then
        'Find the child ComboBox window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "ComboBox", "")
        Debug.Print "   ComboBox "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If

    If hWnd Then
        SetForegroundWindow hWnd

        'Find the child Edit window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "Edit", "")
        Debug.Print "   Edit "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If

    If hWnd Then        
        'Click the Save button
        SetForegroundWindow hWnd
        Sleep 600  'this sleep is required and 600 milliseconds seems to be the minimum that works
        SendMessage hWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any way (that won't get me in trouble with IT!) that I can inspect the handle numbers of the IE elements? Code inspector only shows me the page code, not IE dialogues.

Is there a list of possible element names for `lpsz1` defined somewhere, as they apply to elements of IE?

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
```

Comment: You mention "Excel 14" - do you mean the Office14 version, aka Office/Excel 2010? Or do you mean Office/Excel 2013?

Comment: It's Office 2010, in the "About" section it states Version:14.0.7208.5000

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the dreaded sendkeys?

```
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
Application.SendKeys "%{O}"
```

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: **~~shudder~~**

Comment: So far, I've got:

Application.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}" 'jump to the save-as
Application.SendKeys "{^A}{^C}" 'copy the current filename

Dim clip As DataObject
Set clip = New DataObject
filename = clip.GetFromClipboard

Application.SendKeys "{HOME}"

SavePath = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Knowledgebase\MS Office\Download Test" & WorkbookFunction.Format(Now(), "YYYY-DD-MM HHMM ")

clip.SetText SavePath
clip.PutInClipboard

Application.SendKeys "{^V}{TAB}~"   'jump to the save button and press enter


... and I can't step the code, or it send the keys to VBA!

Comment: I can't read that in the comments but I can tell you that you would put the two lines of my code at the point you expect the pop-up to appear. You cannot be debugging at the time or it will send to the VBE.

Comment: I'm trying to use save as, and change the target name, which takes 13 keys and a string paste, and I can't step the code. The proper window interfaces sound like a much safer method, if I knew the correct handles to use. Several forums and tutorials state **Use SendKeys as a last resort only**

Comment: it is not ideal, I will admit. But are you sure there isn't a download URL in the associated HTML?

Comment: Nope, generated by a javascript. I've broken the the filenames down, they're linux timestamps. So even if I could figure out a URL that would get me to it, it doesn't exist until the java is invoked to create the file, and I'd need sub-milli-second time sync with the server. :/ Thanks for the suggestion, but I need a solution that pushes that button and reacts to the save file prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In my IE Automation used below code to save file from IE. Below code requires VBA reference to UIAutomationCore.dll and can be found at

> %windir%/sysWow64/UIAutomationCore.dll

and enable trust access to vba by

> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Check Trust access to the VBA

```
Private Sub InvokeSaveButton(IEHwnd As Long)
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h As Long
h = IEHwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nagarajannd, thanks for the look-in. I had found that method in the forums and tried to use it, firstly I found that I had to declare h as a variant, when I left it as long, the line 'h = ieApp.hWnd' failed on Type Mismatch. Now when I run that code, it crashes XL at 'Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)'. I get that the crash might be caused by sending a variant instead of a long. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396] indicates hWnd should be long, so why do I get a Type Mismatch...? :/

Comment: Ok, Try declaring h as LongPtr.

Comment: Nope, now I get Type Mismatch at `h = FindWindowEx(**h**, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the urlmon library. Change the url and file name + extension to what you need to.

**It will probably not work on a website where you have to log in to get to the file**.

```
Public Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Public Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim errValue As Long
    errValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If errValue = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download Completed, saved at: " & LocalFilename
    Else
        MsgBox "There was an error downloading the file"
    End If
End Function
Sub DoIt()
    DownloadFile "http://www.blahblahblah.com/somefolder/somefiles.xlsx", "C:\Users\Public\Documents\SavedFile.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, direct download to a file is simple, been doing it for years. This application requires a login to the page, then the download is generated by javascript, it's not a hard link - hence the section to find the button called Download and click it.